# AHK stuck with function with value outside of it

Tags: autohotkey

Those if doesn't work, because `test()` doesn't take value from outside, but I have no clue how I should write code if I put it inside...

Any suggestions?

```
SetTimer, test, 2000    ;I started off with 1000 then worked up to this number to confirm this was happening
number := 1
test:
    test()
return
test(){
    if WinActive("program") {   
    ImageSearch, foundX, foundY, 2000, 0, 2560, 1440, target.png
        if (ErrorLevel = 1) {
            if (number = 1) {
            CheckMap(z := "star.png")
            number := 2
            }
            if (number = 2) {
            CheckMap(z := "like.png")
            number := 3
            }
            if (number = 3) { 
            CheckMap(z := "question.png")
            number := 4
            }
            if (number = 4) {
            CheckMap(z := "cross.png")
            number := 1
            }
        } 
    }
}

CheckMap(x){  
    ImageSearch, foundX, foundY, 2000, 0, 2560, 1440, %x%
    if (ErrorLevel = 0) {
        MouseGetPos, StartX, StartY
        Click, %foundX%, %foundY%
        MouseMove, StartX, StartY
    }
}

*[::
Suspend
Pause, 1
return

*]::
ExitApp
return
```

Answer (score 0):

Found some help, that I needed static number, also fixed if to else if, now works perfect

```
SetTimer, test, 2000    ;

test:
    test()
return
test(){
    static number := 1
    if WinActive("program") {   
    ImageSearch, foundX, foundY, 2000, 0, 2560, 1440, target.png
        if (ErrorLevel = 1) {
            if (number = 1) {
            CheckMap(z := "star.png")
            number := 2
            } else if (number = 2) {
            CheckMap(z := "like.png")
            number := 3
            } else if (number = 3) { 
            CheckMap(z := "question.png")
            number := 4
            } else if (number = 4) {
            CheckMap(z := "cross.png")
            number := 1
            }
        } 
    }
}

CheckMap(x){  
    ImageSearch, foundX, foundY, 2000, 0, 2560, 1440, %x%
    if (ErrorLevel = 0) {
        MouseGetPos, StartX, StartY
        Click, %foundX%, %foundY%
        MouseMove, StartX, StartY
    }
}

*[::
Suspend
Pause, 1
return

*]::
ExitApp
return
```

Comment: A static variable indeed is one solution. If you would've wanted to use a variable from outside of the function's scope, `global` would've been what you're looking for. Read more about variable scopes [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm#Locals).